# Sharepoint:SaveAsDraft button not rendering

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom 'New' form for a list in Sharepoint Designer 2010. I added a sharepoint saveasdraft button in the code.

```
<SharePoint:SaveAsDraftButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" ID="SaveasDraft1"/>
```

The button is also visible in the design mode. But when I preview it in the browser the button is not visible. The table cell which contains the button is rendered.

Does any body know as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?